# Ember.js helpers and Handlebars.js (runtime-only build)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there any way to precompile Handlebars template, so that it will be aware about Ember.js helpers, like "action", "view", etc.?

The reason I'm asking is because I need to use Ember.js with a runtime-only build of the Handlebars (due to CSP in Google Chrome), and it seems that Ember.js does not completely support currently such scenario:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1303

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can precompile an Ember Handlebars template using `Ember.Handlebars.precompile` ([ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L104](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L104)).

The basic strategy to use for precompilation outside of a browser (in node, for example) is:

- Load handlebars.js
- Load ember.js
- Shim out a few browser APIs that Ember expects (this should not be necessary in 1.0, but it is necessary today).
- `template = Ember.Handlebars.precompile(string)`
- `Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = Ember.Handlebars.template(template)`

The `ember-rails` gem for Rails does this for you if you have an asset with the extension `.handlebars`.

The `ember-rails` gem also maintains a shim `.js` file that you can use to precompile in other non-browser environments ([ember-precompiler.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/lib/ember/handlebars/assets/ember-precompiler.js)).